# Segue infinite loop in prepareforsegue

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue

I have built a table view where one of the rows needs to go to a special view controller. I built an if statement into the prepareforsegue function to handle this, but I'm getting an infinite loop.

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    NSIndexPath *myIndexPath = [self.tableView
                            indexPathForSelectedRow];

    long row = [myIndexPath row];
    if([_categoryTitle[row] isEqualToString:@"About"]){
        NSLog(@"ABOUT");
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"aboutCat" sender:self];
    }
    else if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"ShowLocationsTableView"])
    {
        NSLog(@"ELSE");
        LocationsTableViewController *ViewController =
        [segue destinationViewController];

        ViewController.categoryDetailModel = @[_categoryTitle[row],
                                            _categoryImages[row]];
    }
}
```

When I click on the about row, I receive no change in view and the console prints an infinite steam of "About". Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 4):

You must not perform a segue in `prepareForSegue`. That is the source of the infinite loop.

If this row is trying to perform the wrong segue, prevent it with `shouldPerformSegue` (and now you can do something else).

Answer (score 0):

Because you have not written any code for performing the segue when `aboutCat` is there

```
else if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"aboutCat"])
{
     // code for performing aboutcat
}
```